# Change Location of .drone.yml

Tags: drone.io

Is there a way to change the location of the .drone.yml file. We would like to have it placed in a sub-directory of our parent project.

Answer (score 0):

There's a drone-wide environment option named DRONE_YAML that can be set; the default value is `.drone.yml`, so given you'd want to move it to a subdirectory `build`, then add this to the *dronerc* file:

`DRONE_YAML=build/.drone.yml`

(Untested, deduced from the drone source code)